# Why are elf segments not page aligned?

Tags: elf

`readelf -l /bin/ls`:

```
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x18ff8 0x18ff8 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x019eec 0x08061eec 0x08061eec 0x003f4 0x01014 RW  0x1000
```

So the boundary page between the two segments is both read-only and read-writable, how is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming a page size of 4096 (0x1000) bytes and rounding addresses to page granularities:

- The first loadable segment would use the address range [0x8048000--0x8060FFF], both ends inclusive.
- The second loadable segment would use the address range [0x8061000--0x8062FFF], of which 0x3F4 bytes starting at address 0x8061EEC would come from the executable, with the rest being zero-filled at load time.

There is no overlap.

Comment: why doesnt the second segment start at ox8061000?

Comment: @user1608776 Good question. You may need to look at the linker map for `/bin/ls` to determine the data being placed between offsets 0x8061000 and 0x8061EEC.  Looking at the linker map for a simpler (hello world) executable, the corresponding offset range seems to be being used for sections named `.tdata`, `.tbss` and `.gcc_except_table`.

Comment: @jkoshy: "The second loadable segment would use the address range [0x8061000--0x8062FFF], of which 0x3F4 bytes starting at address 0x8061EEC would come from the executable, with the rest being zero-filled at load time.". Are you sure that the rest is zero filled?

Comment: @Berk7871 Maybe not. Actually the loader just map the entire page from elf file. So it may contains something else. You can use gdb to check the content.